# MS Word | hide/show text of section by clicking on it

Tags: microsoft-word

I am wondering if it is possible to create something like this below using MS Word. I have a few titles. When I press on these I want more detailed instructions to appear under it. (This is exaclty what I am looking for https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/products/windows?os=windows-10)

Example list:
Install Windows
Configure Windows
Install Notepad

Example list when I have pressed on "Install Windows":
Install Windows
 1. Download the installation media from Microsoft's website.
 2. Install it using USB.
 3. Reboot PC.
Configure Windows
Install Notepad

Thanks in advance!

edit: Found a way to do this using macros but I would like to have all paragraph sections hidden per default when I open the document. This is what I have done so far.

Created a heading with ctrl+f9 = {MACROS INSTALL WINDOWS}
Typed some text below the heading, selected it and attached it to a bookmark called list1.

Pressed ctrl+f11 and input this code
Sub macros()
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("list1").Range.Font.Hidden = Not ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("list1").Range.Font.Hidden
End Sub

How do I make all bookmarks hidden until the headings are pressed? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be in Word? It can be done by cheating a bit, but remember that Word is meant for putting stuff onto paper, in the end...

Comment: I can switch over to another app if it is impossible to preform in MS Word. I just have one requirment - must be able to save it as a pdf.

Comment: ... If that's your requirement, then using Word is not the correct tool... Again, PDFs are meant to be printed, or at least in a format that would be suitable on paper... It's not meant for "rich media", such as the Internet (i.e. HTML5)